# Upgrade JDK to 11 within a project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11

This is NOT a duplicate Question. My problem is I want to change my JDK from 8 to another version (11 or 12) but this error appeared:

**'selected directory is not a valid home for jdk'**

My JDk address is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2

IntelliJ version: 2017.2.5

I've searched about 3 hours, but the problem not fixed.

Comment: Does that `jdk-11.0.2` actually contain a JDK?

Comment: You should probably update intellij, current version is 2019.1 the JDK structure changed with JDK 9, so the old IDE probably doesn't recognize it.

Comment: You will want to use 2019.1 for Java 12, if not the version after once it becomes available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java 11 is supported [from IntelliJ 2018.2 forward](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/06/java-11-in-intellij-idea-2018-2/). You have an outdated IntelliJ 2017.2.5 which most likely doesn't support this language version.

If you plan to code against Java 11 you need to update your IntelliJ.